# is opening DNZ will cause security problem?

Tags: security, port, dmz

I build a home server with Xampp. When route my local ip addres with NAT there is virtual server and DNZ. If I only full fiel virtual server my  http port not opens.if I enable DNZ then I can reach my server from internet.But should I open all of this? are they will cause any security problem?and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Opening a small server to a DMZ connection is **not** recommended at all.  Yes, that would open it up to security vulnerabilities.

The best way of doing this is to discover the specific ports and protocols that your server needs to use, and create port-forward or virtual server rules to just allow those ports to go out.

Comment: I made it with virtual server and opened only 80 port.but it not`s openin. if I allow DNZ it allows

Comment: It sounds like your virtual server settings are not properly configured then.

I would first try to open all ports via the virtual server settings.  This, in theory, should mimick a DMZ setup.  Once that is working, then try closing off the unused ports.

Comment: I opened all ports in Virtual server and closed firewall on router but it is not allows. Also I can send  ping from other computer to my computer which server setuped but I can`t see my web page like htpp://192.168.1.10/mysite/index.html   it does not work.